# Infinite loop on while PHP

Tags: php, date, while-loop, infinite-loop, strtotime

First of all, im not a programmer (just have some knowledge of PHP). 
I made a website with event listing with a select field filtering per month events with Ajax loading.

The code worked perfect for about 3 months. But sudenly 5 days ago, it stoped working and start generating an infinite loop.

I debugged the code and found that a "while" loop is the problem.
I'm trying to understand why this worked perfect for some time, and then it just won't. (crashing the server with an infinite loop).

This function just gives the first day of next month. It's working fine.

```
function first_day_next_month($month, $year){

  $month = str_replace("0", "", $month);

  if ($month == 12){
    return ($year+1)."0101";
  }else{
    return $year.str_pad($month+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT )."01";
  }

}
```

This one, generates the "options" for the select field:

```
function ddown(){

  $start = strtotime("10 December 2017");

  $end = strtotime("+3 months");

  $current = $start;

  $meses = array(

    "Jan" => "enero",
    "Feb" => "febrero",
    "Mar" => "marzo",
    "Apr" => "abril",
    "May" => "mayo",
    "Jun" => "junio",
    "Jul" => "julio",
    "Aug" => "agosto",
    "Sep" => "septiembre",
    "Oct" => "octubre",
    "Nov" => "noviembre",
    "Dec" => "diciembre"

    );
  $o = "";

  $selected = "";
  $cls = " class=\"gray-out\"";
  while ($current < $end){

    if(date("m", $current) == date("m", strtotime("today")) AND date("Y", $current) == date("Y", strtotime("today"))){
      $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";
      $cls = "";
    }else{
      $selected = "";
    }



    $current = strtotime(first_day_next_month( date("m", $current), date("Y", $current) ));
  }

  return $o;

}
```

I found out that this piece of the code is generating the infinte loop now:

```
while ($current < $end){

    if(date("m", $current) == date("m", strtotime("today")) AND date("Y", $current) == date("Y", strtotime("today"))){
      $selected = " selected=\"selected\"";
      $cls = "";
    }else{
      $selected = "";
    }



    $current = strtotime(first_day_next_month( date("m", $current), date("Y", $current) ));
  }
```

The $current variable is not updating on the while. AS far as I understand this should take the 10 december 2017 to today+3 months and output and "option" for every month between those dates.

Any advice on how to solve this?.

(sorry for my english).

Thanks!

Comment: every use of strtotime to time should be replaced with http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first_day_next_month function you have:

```
$month = str_replace("0", "", $month);
```

This is going to replace 10 with 1 which will revert every October back to January.

Comment: Wow, i didn't see that. Thats exactly where the problems is. As i didnt write this code i'm trying to understand why that line was in there. Can you see any logic on it?. Im going to delete it and see if everything works.

Comment: Assuming whoever wrote it was trying to trim the 0 from the front of the single digit months, but there's no need to do that as far as I can see.

Comment: I deleted that line and now everything works perfect. Thanks a lot, u saved my day.